# Automatically identify a suitable type, large enough and precise enough, to hold the sum of all elements in a container

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype

*(This question has been dramatically edited from the original, without changing the real intent of the original question)*

If we add up all the elements in a `vector<int>`, then the answer could overflow, requiring something like `intmax_t` to store the answer *accurately* and *without overflow*. But `intmax_t` isn't suitable for `vector<double>`.

I could manually specify the types:

```
template<typename>
struct sum_traits;

template<>
struct sum_traits<int> {
    typedef long accumulate_safely_t;
};
```

and then use them as follows:

```
template<typename C>
auto sum(const C& c) {
    sum_traits<decltype(c.begin())> :: accumulate_safely_t> r = 0;
    for(auto &el: c)
        r += el;
    return r;
}
```

My questions: Is it possible to automatically identify a suitable type, a large and accurate type, so I don't have to manually specify each one via the type trait?

Comment: You know `r` is going to be an int so why not just use that?

Comment: possible in c++14.

Comment: because the container element type may be different and the result may be greater than the value that can store this type

Comment: yes but c++11 not used that

Comment: It might help to clarify your question as follows: You expect the return type to depend on the type of the members of the collection `c`. It must be precise *and* large. I think you basically have to use either `long double` or `intmax_t`, choosing one automatically based on whether `c`'s member are of integral type

Comment: Yes, but need a more general solution.

Comment: @Cfon : "I need a more general solution". To what problem?

Comment: It's quite important for you to state what you actually want to achieve. The way you want to do it doesn't feel right. How about creating a class that works like integer but is able to store numbers with infinite many digits, some sort of integer chain (of course that will hardly work with other types like float)? Of course this would be slower and for such considerations we need the context.

Comment: I've just very dramatically overhauled the question. @Cfon, feel free to undo my edit if you feel that I have misrepresented your question

Comment: Why containers? Can't you ask this same question about adding just two things?

Comment: He wants to be able to accumulate the elements of an arbitrary container, of arbitrary length, with a guarantee of no overflow.    No general solution is possible to that.   Consider a `std::vector<unsigned long long>` with number of elements equal to `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()` and each element equal to `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()`.  There is no type deducible by the compiler that can exactly represent the sum of all elements of that container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [return type deduction](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3386.html) in C++14 just like this:

```
template<typename C>
auto sum(const C& c) {
    auto r = 0;
    for(auto &el: c)
        r += el;
    return r;
}
```

In C++11, considering your C++98 code, you may use the following:

```
template<typename C>
auto sum(const C& c) -> typename C::value_type {
    auto r = 0;
    for(auto &el: c)
        r += el;
    return r;
}
```

But, as pointed in the comments, `auto r = 0;` will still resolve to `int` at compile time. As proposed in an other answer, you may want to make the initial value type (and so the return value type) a template parameter as well:

```
template<typename C, typename T>
T sum(const C& c, T init) {
    for(auto &el: c)
        init += el;
    return init;
}

// usage

std::vector<std::string> v({"Hello ", "World ", "!!!"});
std::cout << sum(v, std::string{});
```

Comment: But, as mentioned by Gill Bates, the c++14 version returns `int` contrary to your c++11 version.

Comment: `auto r = 0;` will still resolve to `int` at compile time.

Comment: BTW, `typename C::value_type` is shorter than `decltype(typename C::value_type())` and works for non default constructible type.

Comment: auto sum(const C& c) -> typename C::value_type 
what we need!

Answer (score 4):

The main problem with your code is that `auto r = 0` is equivalent to `int r = 0`. That's not how your C++98 code worked. In general, you can't find a perfect target type. Your code is just a variant of `std::accumulate`, so we can look at how the Standard solved this problem: it allows you to pass in the initial value for the accumulator, but also its type: `long sum = std::accumulate(begin, end, long{0});`

Comment: Thanks! but can do it with auto and decltype in C++11?

Comment: @Cfon: That's the problem: do **what**? What do you want the return type to be? The compiler isn't psychic, nor are we. In particular, what should the return value be when the container is empty? And is it supposed to work when the container is `std::vector<std::string>` ? With `std::accumulate`, we can pass `std::string{}` as the initial value.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

> If we add up all the elements in a vector, then the answer could overflow, requiring something like intmax_t to store the answer accurately and without overflow.

Question:

> My questions: Is it possible to automatically identify a suitable type, a large and accurate type, so I don't have to manually specify each one via the type trait?

The problem here is that you want to take runtime data (a vector) and from it deduce a type (a compile-time thing).

Since type deduction is a compile-time operation, we must use only the information available to us at compile time to make this decision.

The only information we have at compile-time (unless you supply more) is `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` and `std::numeric_limits<std::vector<int>::size_type>::max()`.

You don't even have `std::vector<int>::max_size()` at this stage, as it's not mandated to be `constexpr`. Neither can you rely on `std::vector<int>::allocator_type::max_size()` because it's:

1. a member function
2. optional
3. deprecated in c++17

So what we're left with is a maximum possible sum of:

`std::numeric_limits<int>::max() * std::numeric_limits<std::vector<int>::size_type>::max()`

we could now use a compile-time disjunction to find an appropriate integer (if such an integer exists) (something involving `std::conditional`)

This doesn't make the type adapt to runtime conditions, but it will at least adapt to the architecture for which you're compiling.

Something like this:

```
template <bool Signed, unsigned long long NofBits>
struct smallest_integer
{
    template<std::size_t Bits, class...Candidates>
    struct select_candidate;

    template<std::size_t Bits, class...Candidates>
    using select_candidate_t = typename select_candidate<Bits, Candidates...>::type;

    template<std::size_t Bits, class Candidate, class...Rest>
    struct select_candidate<Bits, Candidate, Rest...>
    {
        using type = std::conditional_t<std::numeric_limits<Candidate>::digits >= Bits, Candidate, select_candidate_t<Bits, Rest...>>;
    };

    template<std::size_t Bits, class Candidate>
    struct select_candidate<Bits, Candidate>
    {
        using type = std::conditional_t<std::numeric_limits<Candidate>::digits >= Bits, Candidate, void>;
    };

    using type =
    std::conditional_t<Signed,
    select_candidate_t<NofBits, std::int8_t, std::int16_t, std::int32_t, std::int64_t, __int128_t>,
    select_candidate_t<NofBits, std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t, __uint128_t>>;
};

template<bool Signed, unsigned long long NofBits> using smallest_integer_t = typename smallest_integer<Signed, NofBits>::type;

template<class L, class R>
struct result_of_multiply
{
    static constexpr auto lbits = std::numeric_limits<L>::digits;
    static constexpr auto rbits = std::numeric_limits<R>::digits;
    static constexpr auto is_signed = std::numeric_limits<L>::is_signed or std::numeric_limits<R>::is_signed;
    static constexpr auto result_bits = lbits + rbits;

    using type = smallest_integer_t<is_signed, result_bits>;
};

template<class L, class R> using result_of_multiply_t = typename result_of_multiply<L, R>::type;

struct safe_multiply
{
    template<class L, class R>
    auto operator()(L const& l, R const& r) const -> result_of_multiply_t<L, R>
    {
        return result_of_multiply_t<L, R>(l) * result_of_multiply_t<L, R>(r);
    }
};

template<class T>
auto accumulate_values(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    using result_type = result_of_multiply_t<T, decltype(std::declval<std::vector<T>>().max_size())>;
    return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), result_type(0), std::plus<>());
}

struct uint128_t_printer
{

    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        auto n = n_;
        if (n == 0)  return os << '0';

        char str[40] = {0}; // log10(1 << 128) + '\0'
        char *s = str + sizeof(str) - 1; // start at the end
        while (n != 0) {

            *--s = "0123456789"[n % 10]; // save last digit
            n /= 10;                     // drop it
        }
        return os << s;
    }
    __uint128_t n_;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const uint128_t_printer& p)
{
    return p(os);
}

auto output(__uint128_t n)
{
    return uint128_t_printer{n};
}

int main()
{
    using rtype = result_of_multiply<std::size_t, unsigned>;
    std::cout << rtype::is_signed << std::endl;
    std::cout << rtype::lbits << std::endl;
    std::cout << rtype::rbits << std::endl;
    std::cout << rtype::result_bits << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<rtype::type>::digits << std::endl;

    std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    auto z = accumulate_values(v);
    std::cout << output(z) << std::endl;


    auto i = safe_multiply()(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max(), std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max());
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```